# function won't return q -Javascript

Tags: javascript, return

I have the following function:

```
  "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#slider,input[type='range']").on("mousemove touchmove ",function(){
            $("#test").html($(this).val())
        });
    });

        function AddClass(){
            var q=0;
            var p=prompt("Enter the class(es) you want to add seperated by a ','");
            var to_be_added=[];
            to_be_added=p.split(",");
            for (var j=0;j<to_be_added.length;j++){
                if(to_be_added[j][0] === "."){
                    to_be_added[j]=to_be_added[j].slice(1);//check if the first character of each class inside an array contains "." and remove it
                }
            }
            for (var k=0;k<to_be_added.length;k++){
                $("#slider").addClass(to_be_added[k]);
                q++;
            }
            return "q";
        }
        function delclass(){
            var q=0;
            var p=prompt("Enter the class(es) you want to remove seperated by a ','");
            var to_be_added=[];
            to_be_added=p.split(",");
            for (var j=0;j<to_be_added.length;j++){
                if(to_be_added[j][0] === "."){
                    to_be_added[j]=to_be_added[j].slice(1);//check if the first character of each class inside an array contains "." and remove it
                }
            }
            for (var k=0;k<to_be_added.length;k++){
                $("#slider").removeClass(to_be_added[k]);
                q++;
            }
            return "Hello";

        }
```

html:

```
<button onclick="delclass()">Delete</button>
```

The problem is that after running the above code i don't get anything in the console.Not even undefined.Any ideas?Jquery is included and $("#slider") is correct.
Update
If call the function from the console i will get "Hello" in the console but when i use button to call that function i get nothing

Comment: Where are you calling said function?

Comment: My guess is $("#slider") is incorrect.  Rest of code is correct.  Do you have jQuery added and does slider exist?

Comment: i use onclick attribute on a button

Comment: Can we see *that* code? Nothing here would cause anything to be logged to the console.

Comment: @cssGEEK why do you expect anything in the console? You call the function as an event handler and never use the returned `q` anywhere, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @PaulRoub usualy when i use return inside a function i get an output in the consolle

Comment: in the console, are you getting prompted for class names? Or, is it not getting that far.

Comment: @dave in the console i am getting prompted for classes

Comment: Ok, I read your update.  I'm not following how the prompt would happen when you click the button.  Maybe the `prompt` function can't operate in that context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i use button to call that function i get nothing

This is to be expected. The console does not show the return value of every function that executes in your code. If you manually execute code in the console, the console will show you the result of that execution. That is different from having code execute in your page.

Returning a value from an event handler does nothing, and it certainly does not output anything to the console.

If you want to display a value in the console, use `console.log`:

```
console.log("Hello");
```